# Get order shipping address in module

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm trying to add an address column to my orders index but I'm having trouble correctly getting the actual address.

From my code below, when I dump on `$orderShippingAddress` I get the ID of a valid address. But when I dump on `$address` I get `null`.

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong? For reference, I was working from here: https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/addresses.html#get-current-customer-address-by-id

```
Event::on(
    Order::class,
    Order::EVENT_REGISTER_TABLE_ATTRIBUTES,
    function (RegisterElementTableAttributesEvent $event) {
        $event->tableAttributes['address'] = ['label' => 'Address'];
    }
);  

Event::on(
    Order::class,
    Order::EVENT_SET_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE_HTML,
    function (SetElementTableAttributeHtmlEvent $event) {
        $order = $event->sender;
        $orderShippingAddress = $order->shippingAddressId;
        $address = craft\commerce\Plugin::getInstance()->getCustomers()->getCustomer()->getAddressById($order->shippingAddressId);
        dump($shippingAddress);
        if ($event->attribute === 'address') {
             $event->html = $address;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: What do you get if you just use the `addresses` service? `$address = craft\commerce\Plugin::getInstance()->getAddresses()->getAddressById($order->shippingAddressId);`

Comment: Nice one! That does it!

Comment: @MartinSpain if you add that as an answer I'll mark it accepted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Addresses](https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/api/v3/craft-commerce-services-addresses.html#public-methods) service to get the shipping address:

```
$address = craft\commerce\Plugin::getInstance()->getAddresses()->getAddressById($order->shippingAddressId);
```

This is the more direct method to get the address, and it's a bit shorter to type too!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `$order->getShippingAddress()` which is even shorter! :)