# `SetElementTableAttributeHtmlEvent` with an array

Tags: modules

Second to my [other question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/39288/get-order-shipping-address-in-module) about adding a column to the orders index, I would now like to add a column looping over the products in the order.

How can I do that when then [`SetElementTableAttributeHtmlEvent`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-events-setelementtableattributehtmlevent.html) `html` property wants a string?

```
function (SetElementTableAttributeHtmlEvent $event) {
    $order = $event->sender;
    if ($event->attribute === 'products') {
        $lineItems = $order->lineItems;
        foreach ($lineItems as $lineItem) {
            $event->html = $lineItem->description;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought maybe something like this would work `$event->html = implode('|', $lineItem->description);` but I get `TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `implode` on a single description, this won't work. You need to map the array of `LineItem` objects to an array of strings (containing the description), then call `implode` on that.

It should work like this:

```php
$lineItems = $order->lineItems;
$descriptions = array_column($lineItems, 'description');
$event->html = implode(' | ', $descriptions);
```

[`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) works well if you want a single property (like the description) from all line items. If you want multiple properties or a custom format, you can use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) instead to map the array of line items to an array of strings with a custom format:

```php
$lineItems = $order->lineItems;
$descriptions = array_map(
    fn($lineItem) => "{$lineItem->description} ({$lineItem->qty})",
    $lineItems,
);
$event->html = implode(' | ', $descriptions);
```

This will result in something like `First item (2) | Second item (1)`.

Comment: Thank you! So now if I wanted to also show the quantity for each line item, how could I do that?
`$lineItems = $order->lineItems;
$descriptions = array_column($lineItems, 'description');
$quantity = array_column($lineItems, 'qty');
$event->html = implode(' | ', $descriptions) . implode('', $quantity);`

This ends up like 'First Item | Second Item21' (which makes sense)

Comment: @brynli64 Use array_map instead of array_column, I've updated my answer with a code example for that!

Comment: Updoot for a really elegant use of arrow functions!

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks @MoritzLost!